# Find the last element in a sum of elements that is equal to or greater than the input (formula, no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I think this is a tricky one.

I'm trying to make a bucket system where you put in a number and you sum up cells in a line until they are equal to or larger than your number. Then you select that cell.

EG below.

```
Input is 3. 
A = 0
A+B = 1
A+B+C = 3 
Answer is C

Input is 4
A+B+C = 3 
A+B+C+D = 6
Answer is D because it's the next bracket up.
```

[image]

Pretty easy algorithm to do in a macro but I'm trying to avoid VBA.

Comment: If your input is 4 then what would be output?

Comment: If my input is 4 then the output would be the next bracket that can hold that value, D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=XLOOKUP(B1,SCAN(0,B3:B10,LAMBDA(κ,λ,κ+λ)),A3:A10,,1)`

Comment: I pulled a co-worker into my office to bask in the pure wizardry that was your answer. I've accepted it as the answer and implemented into my worksheet. Thankyou Jos.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you use a helper column. As per my below screenshot I have used `=SUM($B$3:$B3)` to <kbd>C3</kbd> cell and drag down till need. Then use below formula to get desired result.

```
=@FILTER(A3:C10,C3:C10>=B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Harun, your answer is correct, readable and educational. Thankyou for the reply. 
I would like to mark it as correct but since we also received a technically correct answer without the helper function I felt it was the more appropriate "official" solution.

Comment: @Automationispower Yes, that is how stackoverflow works. Obviously best one should be accepted. I also learn from that answer.